# Selenium with Firefox GeckoDriver list up as WebDriver Present

Tags: python, web-scraping, firefox, geckodriver, selenium4

I was trying to make a selenium bot that executes through firefox geckodriver but when I use AntiBot detection website like (https://bot.sannysoft.com/) it shows WebDriver as present.

[Antibot shows WebDriver as present](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iV7bL.png)

I tried the same test on ChromeDriver it was solved with 2 lines of additions.

```
        self.options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
        self.options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
```

and I'm using the selenium library with version:

```
selenium==4.9.0
```

Heres my code for what I tried but did not work:

```
import pickle

from selenium import webdriver


class ANTIBOT(webdriver.Firefox):
    def __init__(self, teardown=False):

        self.teardown = teardown

        self.firefox_driver_path = r'C:\SeleniumDriver\geckodriver.exe'
        self.firefox_binary_path = r'C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe'
        self.firefox_profile_path = r'C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\p25v0mcm.default-release'

        self.options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
        self.options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')

        self.options.set_preference('profile', self.firefox_profile_path)
        
        self.options.set_preference('network.proxy.type', 1)
        self.options.set_preference('network.proxy.socks', '127.0.0.1')
        self.options.set_preference('network.proxy.socks_port', 9050)
        self.options.set_preference("network.proxy.socks_remote_dns", False)

        self.options.set_preference('dom.webdriver', False)
        self.options.set_preference('enable-automation', False)
        self.options.set_preference('dom.webdriver.enabled', False)
        self.options.set_preference('useAutomationExtension', False)
        self.options.set_preference('devtools.jsonview.enabled', False)
        self.options.set_preference('marionette.enabled', False)
        
        self.options.set_preference('fission.bfcacheInParent', False)
        self.options.set_preference('fission.webContentIsolationStrategy', 0)

        self.options.set_capability('marionette', False)

        self.options.binary_location = self.firefox_binary_path

        self._service = Service(self.firefox_driver_path)

        super(ANTIBOT, self).__init__(
                                options=self.options, 
                                service=self._service, 
                            )

        self.execute_script('Object.defineProperty(navigator, "webdriver", {get: () => undefined})')

        self.implicitly_wait(60)
        # self.maximize_window()

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):

        if self.teardown:
            self.quit()
    
    def save_cookies(self):
        
        pickle_filename = 'cookies.pkl'
        pickle.dump(self.get_cookies(), open(pickle_filename, 'wb'))

    def load_cookies(self):
        
        cookies = pickle.load(open('cookies.pkl', 'rb'))

        if len(cookies) > 0:
            for cookie in cookies:
                self.add_cookie(cookie)

            self.refresh()

    def load_bot_detector(self):

        self.get('https://bot.sannysoft.com/')
        self.implicitly_wait(30)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    with ANTIBOT(teardown=False) as antibot:
        antibot.save_cookies()
        antibot.load_cookies()

        antibot.load_bot_detector()
```